# Sveltekit - consume external REST api inside a component

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-component

Is it possible to consume external REST api in components? With the new breaking changes, I couldn't find an updated answer.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!

You can do a native `fetch` for any `CRUD` operations inside components.

Something similar like this:

```js
let data;

const getData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://your.endpoint/api/foo');
    if (response.headers.get('content-type')?.includes('application/json')) {
        const json = await response.json();
        return { response, json };
    } else {
        return { response };
    }
};
```

Then you can initialize whenever you want. E.g:

```js
onMount(async ()=> {
    await getData();
})
```

Comment: The question is tagged `sveltekit`, so should probably fetch the data in the `load()` function instead. https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load

Answer (score 0):

Good example from docs: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#making-fetch-requests

```
/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export async function load({ fetch, params }) {
  const res = await fetch(`/api/items/${params.id}`);
  const item = await res.json();
 
  return { item };
}
```

Comment: But the question how to use it inside the component not page.